# cascaded calls to variadic functions in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions, c99

I need to make a wrapper of `vprintf`, so that multiple implementations of a printf like function can be done. This code demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void print_fmt2(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}


void print_fmt1(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args, args_copy;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    va_copy(args_copy, args);
    print_fmt2(fmt, args_copy);
    va_end(args_copy);
    va_end(args);
    print_fmt2("\r\n");
}


int main ()
{
  print_fmt1("test return %s %u\r\n", "is", 0);
  return 0;
}
```

The above code, compiled with gcc 11.4, Linux, outputs:

```
test return 3447949600
```

But what I expect and want to achieve is:

```
test return is 0
```

The issue should be with usage of `va_copy` macro, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

I have to stick to C99 standard.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: here is repro https://godbolt.org/z/EM6vYx99c

Comment: On an unrelated note, carriage-return `'\r'` isn't needed in your output. It will be added automatically on the systems that uses it.

Comment: You can have cascaded va_list calls but not cascaded vararg calls.  From the second level onwards, it has to be a va_list

Comment: _Side note:_ When doing your own `printf`, you can get it to be checked at compile time just like `printf` with `-Wall` by adding an attribute: `void __attribute__((__format__(__printf__,1,2))) print_fmt1(const char *fmt,...);`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zaz7bPMP8

Comment: @Eljay Instead of posting comments like that, you can just edit the post to remove the incorrect tags. You have full edit privileges. See the C and C++ tag wikis https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info, tag moderation guidelines: "_If you can tell the language by reading the posted code, simply edit tags accordingly. Avoid prompting the user "is it C or C++?" in comments unless the question is truly unclear._"

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that.

That's why there's always two variants of the standard vararg functions: One vararg function, and one that takes a `va_list` argument.

Like in the example you show there's `vprintf` to use a `va_list` argument. You need to do the same with your functions if you want to "cascade" them.

So you need to have e.g.

```
void print_fmt2(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    vprintf(fmt, args);
}

void print_fmt1(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    print_fmt2(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that using functions.

But you can use function like **macros** to archive what you want:

```
void print_fmt2(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}


#define print_fmt1(...) \
{                               \
    print_fmt2(__VA_ARGS__);    \
    print_fmt2("\r\n");         \
}


int main ()
{
  print_fmt1("test return %s %u\r\n", "is", 0);
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7Mhs8oTd7

Answer (score 0):

> I need to make a wrapper of vprintf ....

In addition to [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78181514/2410359) good answer, as `vprintf()` returns an `int`, so should `print_fmt1()`, `print_fmt2()`.

`*printf()` functions return the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output encoding error occurred ...

```
int print_fmt2(const char *fmt, va_list args) {
  return vprintf(fmt, args);
}

int print_fmt1(const char *fmt, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, fmt);
  int retval = print_fmt2(fmt, args);
  va_end(args);

  if (retval >= 0) {
    int retval2 = printf("\r\n");
    retval = (retval2 < 0) ? retval2 : retval + retval2;
  }

  return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's original code has *undefined behavior* because `vprintf` was called with a parameter of type `va_list` that does not describe a list of arguments that matches the printf format string parameter. The format string contains `%s` followed by `%u`, so it is expecting the `va_list` parameter to describe an argument of type `char *` followed by an argument of type `unsigned int`. However, the `va_list` parameter actually describes another argument of type `va_list`.

Conversion of a list of variadic parameters to a `va_list` is a one way operation. There is no way to convert it back to a list of arguments in a function call. That would not make sense because the number of arguments in a function call is fixed at compile time (considering an argument of type `va_list` to be a single argument that happens to refer to another list of arguments). That is not a problem in practice, because there is nothing that you can do with a function that uses `...` in its prototype that you cannot do with an equivalent function that uses a parameter of type `va_list` in its prototype. If you need to handle both forms, then just write two functions and make the function that has `...` in its prototype be a simple wrapper that calls the equivalent function that has a parameter of type `va_list` to represent the variadic parameters.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void vprint_fmt2(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    vprintf(fmt, args);
}

void print_fmt2(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprint_fmt2(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void vprint_fmt1(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    vprint_fmt2(fmt, args);
    print_fmt2("\r\n");
}

void print_fmt1(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vprint_fmt1(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}


int main ()
{
  print_fmt1("test return %s %u\r\n", "is", 0);
  return 0;
}
```

No `va_copy()` calls were required in the above. Here is a somewhat artificial use of `va_copy()` that changes `vprint_fmt2()` (and therefore `print_fmt2()`) to print the arguments twice:

```
void vprint_fmt2(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    va_list args_copy;
    va_copy(args_copy, args);
    vprintf(fmt, args_copy);
    va_end(args_copy);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
}
```